# How to find and remove unused .aspx files in Website project

Tags: asp.net, file, webforms, vs-web-site-project

Recently I've been working on a big ASP.NET Web Forms site and it has some pages that apparently are not in use anymore, but no one knows for sure (this is an inherited project). Is there a way to know if those .aspx files/pages are being used or referenced?

This is not a Web Application Project but a Web Site Project; so I guess it's more difficult to find what .aspx pages are being used and which ones are not. if anyone has experienced something like this, what was your approach to clean this up?

Comment: Not "automatically". Url string pointing to any page may be present in code, markup, other storage such database or files.

Comment: Thanks @igor. I removed "automatically" from the question and tried to explain it in a better way

Answer (score 1):

No, probably not. What would be the criteria for that, if `no one knows for sure`? If you developers can't tell, how would some automatic system decide this for you? You don't need to have .aspx referenced in code for them to be used.

You can use `search` function in VS to find references inside the project, but in a big website like yours it might be kinda slow and problematic. I'm afraid you'll have to go page by page and figure it out by yourself.